# Destructuring type arguments within function signature in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, destructuring

Consider the following function that reverses a pair. I'm looking for a way to define an aliases for both input and output that could be used both in the function body and the function's type signature.

```
function reverse<A, B>([a, b]: [A, B]): [B, A] {
  return [b, a];
}
```

I'm hoping I could pass input and output types to reverse as type arguments since that would make more sense to the caller than `A` and `B` that are more like implementation details of the two.

```
function reverse<I extends [infer A, infer B], O implements [B, A]>([a, b]: I): O {
  return [b, a];
}
```

As an experiment, I tried to do the following. However, it doesn't work since the output is not guaranteed to *extend* `[B, A]`.

```
function reverse<A, B, I extends [A, B], O extends [B, A]>([a, b]: I): O {
  return [b, a];
}
```

Is there some other way to make this work?

Comment: Why do you need to type the array explicitly inside the function body?

Comment: @AlekseyL. I removed that requirement and rewrote the question to have a more clear focus on type argument destructuring

Comment: If you're OK with using type assertion you can go with something like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgSwE4B4CCAaKAhAfFAXigG1McBdAbgChRIoAlCANwiQGcJ5kUAVfIrygQAHsAgA7ACbtYiVAgkAzNlDKKVSHPgD8JbFjTkoALigSWbGtQDGAewntgUJJY7QifYWMky5PAFcJAGsJOwB3CSwg0IiJXFwACmI4LAAjcjNeAEpCfGI0rDhjOFkmVnduVH4oalsHJyglOztCFzdOZOAkAIgsAHInJH7ybMogA

Comment: You could also go with `return [b, a] as const;` then you don't need to provide explicit return type for a function - it will be inferred automatically

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply create type aliases for the Tuples?

```
type Tuple<Y, Z> = [Y, Z];

function reverse<A, B>([a, b]: Tuple<A, B>): Tuple<B, A> {
    return [b, a];
}
```

or even

```
type Tuple<Y, Z> = [Y, Z];
type ReverseTuple<Y, Z> = [Z, Y];

function reverse<A, B>([a, b]: Tuple<A, B>): ReverseTuple<A, B> {
    return [b, a];
}
```

Comment: That would be only a cosmetic change. You are still passing type arguments `A` and `B` to reverse separately.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't completely sure of what you were asking, I'll update my answer.